# Appropriate clothing for Tish B'AV

Tags: tisha-bav

Could it be acceptable to wear a kittle for 9 Av? I've never seen it, I usually wear black or dark grey.
I wouldn't dare try to look innocent- I am guilty and I know it, but that doesn't stop me from wearing white on Yom Kippur. YK is about atonement, can 9 Av be about atonement also?

Comment: Tisha bav is a day of aveilus/remembrance not atonement

Comment: @Chatzkel the geonim recited slichot on Tisha Bav like all fast days. Not sure if anyone still does that

Comment: @double AA that might be because it’s no worse than any other fast day which is a day for Teshuva. The white on YK is because of the promised Kappara which is similar to Rosh Chodesh perhaps. Nobody wears white on Taanis Esther for example

Answer (score 3):

[Rema 551:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.551.3?lang=bi)

> אבל בט' באב עצמו לא תלבש לבנים

> But Tisha B'av itself, she should not wear whites rather wear a garment that is checked and nice [Haagos Shaarei Dora].

Answer (score 0):

One wears a Kittel on Yom Kipper (and at the Seder on Pesach) either because

1. It is due to Simcha (happiness); and one is being like a Malachei Hasharess (ministering angel).
   Or
2. So that one remains humble; one wears a garment that is meant for the deceased.
   (Igros Moshe O.C. 5:61:7 quoting Remah O.C. 610:14)

According to #2, it would be appropriate to wear a Kittel on Tisha Baav. But, as you write, no one seems to do it.